# Encryption function returns different Encrypted key?

Tags: php, encryption

I am using this function to encrypt a string :

```
function encrypt_decrypt($action, $string) 
    {
        $output = false;
        $encrypt_method = 'AES-256-ECB';
        $secret_key = 'gT4ThOvcaFDccFFV21mg5hPzglZsY73T';  
        $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);    
        if ( $action == 'encrypt' ) 
        {
            $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0);
            $output = base64_encode($output);
        } 
        else if( $action == 'decrypt' ) 
        {
            $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0);
        }
        return $output;
    }
```

I am using this function in 2 php files (same function no changes at all )

the only difference between the 2 files is :

**File1.php is getting the string in HTTP GET request:**

```
$Email     = htmlspecialchars($_GET["Email"]);
$ENC_Email = encrypt_decrypt("encrypt",$Email); 
echo($ENC_Email);
```

**and File2.php is getting the very same string from cookies:**

```
$Email  =   $_COOKIE['Email']; 
$enc    =   encrypt_decrypt("encrypt",$Email);
echo($enc);
```

echo of the variable $Email is same in both cases , but the resulting encrypted string is different.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: In the first case, you are converting special chars (like in spanish the ñ) to the equivalent html code for visualitation. You see the same text, but the strings are different. You shouldn't use it

Comment: `"echo of the variable $Email is same in both cases"` - in the browser window or when viewed in source code?

Comment: If you're echoing the variable to a browser you won't see the effect of `htmlspecialchars()`. My guess is that the contents of `$Email` are not the same.

Comment: `echo of the variable $Email is same in both cases`...sure, but as others said, you've preprocessed that value in the first version using htmlspecialchars, so you can expect differences. It's not clear why you did that, or why you didn't think it might be significant. Do you understand what that function does, and why/when it should be used? The only time you need to use it is when you're echoing data into a HTML context. Try your script as `$Email     = $_GET["Email"];
$ENC_Email = encrypt_decrypt("encrypt",$Email); 
echo(htmlspecialchars($ENC_Email));` instead

Comment: as a quick test you could try `echo $_COOKIE['Email']===htmlspecialchars($_GET["Email"]) ? 'identical' : 'different';`?

Comment: Also in the second script you should be writing `echo(htmlspecialchars($enc));` in the the last time, to protect that from XSS attempts too. Just because the data came via a cookie doesn't exempt it from vulnerability - it's still potentially unknown data coming from the client-side.

Comment: I removed` htmlspecialchars` from File1 but the resulting string is still different, I did an echo of `strlen($Email) `in both files and file 2 shows 12 , whereas file 1  shows 11 (11 is correct )

Comment: Perhaps you have a trailing space or something

Comment: yes thats exactly what was causing the issue , I just Dumped the entire string and noticed the whitespace , stupid mistake on my part

Answer (score -1):

It's normal. You encrypt a string, it's not the samething as hashing a string. A hash will give you always the same result. But encryption use random salt, randomIV and differents other random parameters. Then the result is always different.

But, when you decrypt, you must get the string you have encrypted before.

Comment: when I assign the same Email to the $Email variable in both files , the resulting encrypted string is always the same , however when I receive it from the cookies and $GET and process only then it shows different encrypted string 
I did an echo of strlen($Email)  in both files which shows 12 for the file that is reading it from $Cookies which is wrong because there are only 11 characters in the email , and the File with $Get shows 11 characters which is right

Comment: No, this is encrypted in ECB mode. There is no IV at all, and there is no salt here either. The result *should* be the same, which is in fact one of the weaknesses of ECB mode.